# Error after changing ssh port number, Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key

Tags: ssh, configuration, putty

I added the SSH new port number to the `sshd_config` file:

```
Port 50000
```

After that, I restarted the service with

```bash
systemctl restart sshd
```

When I try to connect with the port number I added, I need to connect with the key, but I get this error:

```
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key
```

... and it asks for the password.

I also have to try to connect as something other than root.

The things I've tried are

- Updating putty and pageant.
- Changing the permissions on in the `~/.ssh` directory and `authorized_key` file to `700`/`600`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the output of `ssh -vv` (you'll need to port your keys to work in ssh rather than putty) and the logs on the server.

Comment: The error was caused by a conflict with the port being used by the app.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to regenerate your public/private key pair and update the config on server and client. As the port is actually the part of the URI, the change of port number is probably be the reason why the signature gets rejected.
Make sure to remove the previous key pair in the process.